# Shadow cljs doesn’t see java on Macbook M1

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I used npx **create-cljs-project my-app** and revived error when I tried to start with **npm start**
I have tried few java ask version, but I get same error anyway.

```
shadow-cljs - config: /Users/tomaszsikora/dev/my-app/shadow-cljs.edn
Execution error (UnsatisfiedLinkError) at java.lang.ClassLoader/loadLibrary (ClassLoader.java:2398).
Can't load library: /var/folders/x7/k_6f989d60z2k0pz_cz_3y_40000gn/T/jna1171015707293329039.tmp
Full report at:
/var/folders/x7/k_6f989d60z2k0pz_cz_3y_40000gn/T/clojure-11795200488797552517.edn
```

and it starts like this, but it's too long to paste here.

```
{:clojure.main/message
 "Execution error (UnsatisfiedLinkError) at java.lang.ClassLoader/loadLibrary (ClassLoader.java:2398).\nCan't load library: /var/folders/x7/k_6f989d60z2k0pz_cz_3y_40000gn/T/jna14133068692257536681.tmp\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/class java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError,
  :clojure.error/line 2398,
  :clojure.error/cause
  "Can't load library: /var/folders/x7/k_6f989d60z2k0pz_cz_3y_40000gn/T/jna14133068692257536681.tmp",
  :clojure.error/symbol java.lang.ClassLoader/loadLibrary,
  :clojure.error/source "ClassLoader.java",
  :clojure.error/phase :execution},
 :clojure.main/trace
 {:via
  [{:type java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError,
    :message
    "Can't load library: /var/folders/x7/k_6f989d60z2k0pz_cz_3y_40000gn/T/jna14133068692257536681.tmp",
    :at [java.lang.ClassLoader loadLibrary "ClassLoader.java" 2398]}],
  :trace
```

java version

```
tomaszsikora@DeadBook-Void my-app % java --version
openjdk 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 18.0.2.1+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 18.0.2.1+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Does the file mentioned as `Full report at:` exist and could you add it as well to the question?

Comment: Hi! I just tried it on a Mackbook M1 and it worked. Therefore, I assume it is not related to the M1 processor but something else.
Perhaps it would be helpful if you could post the output of `java --version` and `which java`.

Comment: currently I use this version of java but I have tried others as well